# How to unfold only a child element of its parents own in Class Syntax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, this, prototype

I'm trying to select a child element of its parent own (a.k.a `firstPanel`) in Class Syntax but have no idea how would I do this.

It's easy to refer the each `firstPanel` in the normal function, and it works perfectly fine like this:

```
$(function accordian() {
  $('.mobileCategory').on('click', function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('open')) {
      $(this).addClass('open');
      $(this).siblings('.firstPanel').stop(true, true).animate({
        maxHeight: 1000 + 'px'
      });
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
      $(this).removeClass('open');
      $(this).siblings('.firstPanel').stop(true, true).animate({
        maxHeight: null
      });
    }
  })
})
```

[image]

but when I click the element under the Class Syntax, the whole `.firstPanel` is going to unfold like this:

[image]

I know `this.list` is assuming the entire `firstPanel`. I just don't know how would I refer the child element of the parents own in the Class Syntax.

Are there any ways to do this?

Full Code:

```js
class Accordian {
  constructor($el) {
    this.$el = $el;
    this.category = this.$el.find('.mobileCategory');
    this.list = this.category.siblings();
    /* Boolean Flags */
    this.flags = {
      active: false,
    };
  }
  clicked(e) {
    console.log('text')
    this.list.css({
      maxHeight: 1000 + 'px'
    })
  }
  manange() {
    console.log(this.list, 'text');
    this.$el.on({['click']: (e) => this.clicked(e)});
  }
}
var thatAccordian = new Accordian($('#mobile-menu'));
    thatAccordian.manange();
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
#mobile-menu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 110px);
  top: 110px;
  background-color: #202020;
}
.wrapper, li {
  display: block;
  flex-flow: column;
  margin: 1rem;
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955);
}
.wrapper > li > ul {
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955);
  display: block;
  flex-flow: column;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 1rem;
}
.wrapper > li > ul > li {
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955);
  display: block;
  flex-flow: column;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  font-size: .8rem;
  outline-width: 0;
  border-width: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
  <div id="mobile-menu">
    <ul class="wrapper">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="mobileCategory">MODELS</a>
        <ul class="firstPanel">
          <li>URUS</li>
          <li>HURACÁN</li>
          <li>AVENTADOR</li>
          <li>FEW OFF</li>
          <li>CONCEPT</li>
          <li>AD PERSONAM</li>
          <li>OVERVIEW</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="mobileCategory">BRAND</a>
        <ul class="firstPanel">
          <li>PEOPLE</li>
          <li>HISTORY</li>
          <li>MASTERPIECE</li>
          <li>DESIGN</li>
          <li>INNOVATION & EXCELLENCE</li>
          <li>OVERVIEW</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
      <li><a href="#" class="mobileCategory">MOTORSPORT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="mobileCategory">STORE</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `$(e.currentTarget).siblings('.firstPanel').css(...)`. `this.list` seems useless.

Comment: @FelixKling It works as I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: A jQuery custom plugin would be the most optimal solution.

Comment: @zer00ne That would be the best option but I want to make something by my own.

Comment: @sniffingdoggo custom plugin meaning writing your own small plugin. If done properly it would be roughly as many lines as the OP code or less. BTW you should post the HTML it will help immensely.

Comment: @zero00ne Do you mean this? `(function($, undefined, window) {  $.fn.plugin = function(option) { // do something }}, (jQuery))`

Comment: @sniffingdoggo bingo

Comment: hello, is MODELS an `Accordian` for you? or are all of them (MODELS, BRAND, etc) a single `Accordian`?

Comment: @Scaramouche I don't know what are you exactly saying but MOTORSPORTS and STORE in the picture haven't its own pseudo lists, which mean is it's not an Accordian.

Comment: sorry, maybe I didn't make myself understood. What I meant was: is the whole `#mobile-menu` just one `Accordian` OR is each `.mobileCategory` (with its `ul` sibling, of course) a single `Accordian`?

Comment: @Scaramouche The second one is correct. Each `.mobileCategories` are the `Accordian`

Comment: @Scaramouche Maybe you could understand this way; the `#mobile-menu` is just a big wrapper. A root of the `Accordian` section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, according to your comments, I think you might want to revisit your `Accordian` design. Here are a few pointers:

- You say *each mobileCategories is an Accordian* but, when you create an `Accordian` object like this: `var thatAccordian = new Accordian($('#mobile-menu'));`, you are stating a one-to-one relationship between `thatAccordian` and `#mobile-menu`, wouldn't you say?
- Now take a look at the constructor, when you say `this.$el = $el;`, `this.$el` ends up with `#mobile-menu`, not with one `.mobileCatetgory`; likewise when you write `this.category = this.$el.find('.mobileCategory');`, someone might think, by the name `category` (singular), that `category` ends up with one `.mobileCategory` element, but it doesn't. Try `console.log`-ing it and you'll see how `category` contains ALL (4 in this snippet) category element**s**. Finally, the same occurs with `this.list = this.category.siblings();`; `this.list` will contain ALL (2 in this snippet) `ul`s inside `#mobile-menu` which are siblings of a `.mobileCategory` (which is why two elements are being expanded right now instead of just the one clicked).

So, my advice, check your `Accordian` again but, for the time being, here's a snippet which does what you actually wanted.

As it is right now, inside your `clicked(e)` function, you need to use the event arg (`e`) in order to get the exact element being clicked and then apply whatever style is needed for the animation to it, or its siblings. Also, I recommend adding/removing/toggling CSS classes when possible and creating those classes in the CSS file, instead of editing CSS code from JS.

One last thing, I removed this line `height: calc(100% - 110px);` in the snippet, otherwise the black background was lost when the list was expanded. Also, run the snippet in full screen mode.

HIH

```js
class Accordian {
  constructor($el) {
    this.$el = $el;
    this.category = this.$el.find('.mobileCategory');
    this.list = this.category.siblings();
    
    /* Boolean Flags */
    this.flags = {
      active: false,
    };
  }
  clicked(e) {
    //console.log($(e.target))
    
    $(e.target).siblings('ul').toggleClass('expanded');
    /*this.list.css({
      maxHeight: 1000 + 'px'
    })*/
  }
  manange() {
    //console.log(this.list, 'text');
    this.$el.on({['click']: (e) => this.clicked(e)});
  }
}
var thatAccordian = new Accordian($('#mobile-menu'));
    thatAccordian.manange();
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
#mobile-menu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  /*height: calc(100% - 110px);*/
  top: 110px;
  background-color: #202020;
}
.wrapper, li {
  display: block;
  flex-flow: column;
  margin: 1rem;
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955);
}
.wrapper > li > ul {
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955);
  display: block;
  flex-flow: column;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 1rem;
}
.wrapper > li > ul > li {
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955);
  display: block;
  flex-flow: column;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  font-size: .8rem;
  outline-width: 0;
  border-width: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.wrapper > li > ul.expanded{
  max-height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mobile-menu">
    <ul class="wrapper">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="mobileCategory">MODELS</a>
        <ul class="firstPanel">
          <li>URUS</li>
          <li>HURACÁN</li>
          <li>AVENTADOR</li>
          <li>FEW OFF</li>
          <li>CONCEPT</li>
          <li>AD PERSONAM</li>
          <li>OVERVIEW</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="mobileCategory">BRAND</a>
        <ul class="firstPanel">
          <li>PEOPLE</li>
          <li>HISTORY</li>
          <li>MASTERPIECE</li>
          <li>DESIGN</li>
          <li>INNOVATION & EXCELLENCE</li>
          <li>OVERVIEW</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
      <li><a href="#" class="mobileCategory">MOTORSPORT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="mobileCategory">STORE</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @sniffingdoggo, you can do it like that, it's your design in the end. you just need to make sure you initialize properly the class attributes, otherwise it could get tricky to manage in the class functions, as you already saw.

Comment: you are stating a one-to-one relationship between `thatAccordian` and `#mobile-menu`, wouldn't you say? - Yes. Because getting an Object as a `root` element is looking more better and way easier when I want to search its children elements. And setting the variable names as plural is not used to me because my mother language doesn't that much care about singular and plural like how English does ._. Thank you for pointing out with so many advices.

Comment: @sniffingdoggo; but you are writing in english, right :)